# How to force cleveref to change "Definitions 1 and 2" for "Definitions 1 or 2"?

Tags: cleveref

I am using the powerful `cleveref` package in order to manage the references of my Thesis. At some point, I'm doing something similar to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{document}

\begin{definition}\label{d1}
    Whatever.   
\end{definition}

\begin{definition}\label{d2}
    Whatever twice. 
\end{definition}

Then, we can prove our main result if \cref{d1,d2} are satisfied.
\end{document}
```

As you can see in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5ivh.png), I obtain "[...] Definitions 1 and 2".

[image: scnreenshot]

Instead, I would like to get "[...] Definitions 1 or 2". Hence, **how can I force cref to change AND for OR?**

Comment: You can temporarily renew `\crefrangeconjunction` to contain something other than 'and'.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. If you are so keen to write your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Except the correct phrasing, I think, should be in  singular: ‘if `Definition`  1 or 2 `is` satisfied’.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that my grammar sucks! It's always nice to improve the writing of a Thesis...

Comment: The answer by Mico is correct - regarding my comment: there are several conjunction commands (see p. 12-13 in the `cleveref` manual) for different situations. The `pair` command is for two references (so it is the right one to use here) while the `range` command is for >2 continuous references (e.g., `\ref{d1,d2,d3}`, shown as 'Definitions 1 to 3'). For non-continous references there are `\crefmiddleconjunction` and `\creflastconjunction`, e.g., `\ref{d1,d2,d4}` shown as 'Definitions 1, 2 and 4'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could insert the instruction

```
\providecommand\crefpairconjunction{ or }
```

after loading the `cleveref` package. Note that this directive changes the conjunction not only for definitions.

I assume you're aware that the syntactic structure of the sentence

> We can prove our main result if \cref{d1,d2} are satisfied.

isn't exactly stellar. It would be much better, syntactically speaking, if you wrote

> We can prove our main result if either \cref{d1} or \cref{d2} is satisfied.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\providecommand\crefpairconjunction{ or }  % be very careful...
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}\label{d1} Whatever. \end{definition}
\begin{definition}\label{d2} Whenever. \end{definition}

We can prove our main result if \cref{d1,d2} are satisfied.

We can prove our main result if either \cref{d1} or \cref{d2} is satisfied.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's always nice to come here to learn Latex, and learn Latex plus English grammar instead. Having said so, why using `\providecommand\crefpairconjunction{ or }` after `\begin{document}` has no effect? In case I had to use it, I would only want it for a specific paragraph. Anyway, I think I may end up choosing the option of re-writing. Can I change such a parameter for a single paragraph?

Comment: @Héctor - `\providecommand` creates a command if it (the command) hasn't been defined already, and it does nothing if the command already exists. I.e., it won't overwrite an existing command. If you want to change an existing command, you need to use `\renewcommand`. E.g., `\renewcommand\crefpairconjunction{ and }`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this additional information. I have already accepted your answer.