# cleveref list to use "or" instead of "and"

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

Sometimes I would like `\cref{item1,,item2,,item3}` to write "Item 1, Item 2, or Item 3" instead of "Item 1, Item 2, and Item 3".

Can this be done on an ad-hoc basis?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it's not simple. Take a look at sections 8.1.1 and 8.2.3 of [the documentation](http://ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cleveref/cleveref.pdf).
[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436120/how-to-force-cleveref-to-change-definitions-1-and-2-for-definitions-1-or-2?rq=1) has a simpler answer than mine below (but take note of the last comment under the question).
In my answer you need to specify the counter as well:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\crefor}[2]{%
  \crefmultiformat{#1}{\csuse{cref@#1@name}~##2##1##3}%
    { or~\csuse{cref@#1@name}~##2##1##3}%
    {, \csuse{cref@#1@name}~##2##1##3}%
    {, or~\csuse{cref@#1@name}~##2##1##3}%
  \cref{#2}%
  \crefmultiformat{#1}{\csuse{cref@#1@name@plural}~##2##1##3}%
    { and~##2##1##3}{, ##2##1##3}{, and~##2##1##3}%
}
\makeatother
```

You use it as `\crefor{<counter>}{item1,,item2,,item3}`.
You'd also need to create one for `\Cref`, and maybe add in `\crefrangemultiformat` and `\Crefrangemultiformat` as well.
If you want parentheses around equation numbers it will get even more complicated.

I'll let you decide if you want to use the Oxford comma.